# firebase deploy command not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

so for the past few weeks I've been developing a swift App that connects to Firebase. I have also started working on writing my own cloud functions and deploying them from my macbook using firebaseCLI. However, today when I continued my work on the cloud functions, the command 'firebase deploy' executes but never finishes. From this point onwards it just stops.

I've repeatedly tried to reinstall dependencies and rerunning `firebase deploy`, but to no avail. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: The process can take several minutes to complete. Have you given it 10 minutes or so?

Comment: I did. What happens is at some point the token expires...

Comment: When I tried reinstalling using npm the entire firebaseCLI, this happens: 
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@4.2.1

Comment: According to the support page, there is a service disruption in Cloud Functions. Check back here and see if you're still having problem once the service is back up: https://status.firebase.google.com

Comment: Ah, I see Jen! Thank you for letting me know. I checked the statuspage when I was experiencing the problem but at that point in time there were no disruptions reported by firebase. Perhaps one of the reasons is that I'm coding from The Netherlands and it was night in the US when I was experiencing my problem.